# document.getElementById call to inner html works with $_POST and $_GET variables but not with ordinary php variables

Tags: javascript, php

I'm quite baffled. I can put in variables from a $_GET or $_POST array into the innerHTML of an element, but I can't put in the text from an ordinary php variable. Here's my code:

```
$msg = "We don't recognize that password. Please try again.";
echo "<script>document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='".$msg."';</script>";
//echo "<script>document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='".$_POST['email']."';</script>";
```

The commented out line works great, but the one using $msg doesn't. I've also tried this without success, so substituting in plain old text doesn't work either.

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='hello';</script>";
```

Any ideas about what else I could try? I want to print something other than a $_POST or $_GET variable to the screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the message, it contains a single quote that breaks it

```
$msg = "We don't ...."
//            ^ here
```

you end up with

```
document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML= 'We don't ...';
```

Either escape it, remove it or replace it !

Answer (score 2):

Use `json_encode()` when converting a PHP value to Javascript. It will ensure that the value is quoted and escaped properly. It also allows you to transfer more arrays to JS (JSON is a subset of Javascript literal notation for objects and arrays).

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML=".json_encode($msg).";</script>";
```

Since this quotes the value, you don't need to include quotes in the JS part of the assignment.

Comment: @Barmer thanks for this tip. I had actually tried json_encode, but I had used surrounding single quotes within the js which must have been why it didn't work. I'll remember this for future.